# How can I get the destination address from raw transaction data?

Tags: transactions, address, raw-transaction, output, serialization

I am writing a program that reads Bitcoin transactions from `.blk` files and performs some analysis on them. I would like to get the transaction destination addresses (like in some transaction explorers: [link](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/2221d86b44b270bfee9f83a41bee4153e330817118e0346e2d101227c54b6e05).

Raw transaction data looks like [this](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/transaction-data) and I don't see any address fields anywhere.

How is it possible to calculate it? Is there a (preferably C/C++) program that already does that?
Or are there any details on how to implement this?

Best regards and thanks for all answers in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

> **Raw transaction data looks like this and I don't see any address fields anywhere.**

That's because transactions don't directly involve addresses. An address is an abstraction of a Bitcoin-script used in a transaction. An address is a way for a payee to externally communicate to a payer enough information for the payer to construct an output entry for a new transaction.

> **are there any details on how to implement this?**

See for example https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/p2pkh

[image: Calculating address of P2PKH script]

So for a pay-to-public-key-hash (P2PKH) address you:

- Calculate a Hash160 (SHA256 + RIPEMD160) of the public key
- Prefix that hash with 0x00
- Suffix with a checksum (first four bytes of a SHA256 hash of other data)
- Encode in Base58

You'd need to separately handle address formation for every standard type of Bitcoin-script. Some don't have a standard way to derive an address.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Does any of you know a library (preferably in C++) that would be able to calculate address from given data?